# Need some advice about Three.js 360 panorama

Tags: css, three.js

I am a beginer programer and I am interested with 360 panorama photographing making on three.js engine ( http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_panorama_equirectangular ).
I analyze other examples ( https://ggnome.com/samples/pano2vr_4/tour/ ) I want to ask about how do you make the white dot in panorama picture which alows you to pass to a diferend place in the map to view  the next panorama. How is he merged with that exact part in the sfere? Is it related to THREE.CSS3DRenderer ? 
 Also how do you make the red view arrow (in the mini map)  move along with the panorama. How exacly this is made, does it work with css3 action like transform property (rotate), or it works along side camera rotation the camera rotation axis.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I used this [example](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_video_panorama_equirectangular.html) for training. So I made arrow which I needed with jQuery and CSS transform property. Works perfectly :)

```
        function update() {


            lat = Math.max( - 85, Math.min( 85, lat ) );
            phi = THREE.Math.degToRad( 90 - lat );
            theta = THREE.Math.degToRad( lon );


           //This one

            *$("#nx").text(Math.round(lon,2));
            $('img#siaip').css({'-webkit-transform' : 'rotate(' + lon + 
            'deg)'});*

           //



            camera.target.x = 500 * Math.sin( phi ) * Math.cos( theta );
            camera.target.y = 500 * Math.cos( phi );
            camera.target.z = 500 * Math.sin( phi ) * Math.sin( theta );

            camera.lookAt( camera.target );

            /*
            // distortion
            camera.position.copy( camera.target ).negate();
            */

            renderer.render( scene, camera );

        }
```

Now I stuck on how to make objects to go another panorama. I mean like [this](http://www.vilnius360.lt/) - green flashing object which allows go to another place. I can't understand how to build it. Just thinking that some sphere surface point is related to CSS properties like top, left? Every opinion is important for me.